# How do I download a directory from github

Tags: github

Now I know there are several questions like this on overflow but several of these answers have failed miserably for me. I am using Cygwin, if it is relevant. I ran

```
svn export https://github.com/Wikia/app/tree/dev/extensions/wikia/AdminDashboard
```

to receive the result:

```
svn: E170000: URL 'http://github.com/Wikia/app/tree/dev/extensions/wikia/AdminDashboard' doesn't exist
```

I also ran

```
curl -L http://github.com/Wikia/app/tree/dev/extensions/wikia/AdminDashboard > project.tar.gz
```

to receive a .tar.gz file that 7-Zip fails to read the file giving the error:

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're trying to use `svn` to access GitHub? If you just want to clone part of a repository, look for questions and answers about "sparse checkout". There are tons of them already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two remarks:

- A GitHub repo would not work with svn command
- the url does not exist.

A GitHub repo is best clone in its entirety, but you can do a [sparse checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/sumardi/5559896) or [this article](http://briancoyner.github.io/blog/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout/):

#### New repository

```
mkdir <repo> && cd <repo>
git init
git remote add –f <name> <url>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo some/dir/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo another/sub/tree >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

#### Existing repository

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo some/dir/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo another/sub/tree >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

> If you later decide to change which directories you would like checked out,
>   simply edit the `sparse-checkout` file and run `git read-tree` again as above.